# postfix doesn't authenticate through /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd

Tags: postfix, chroot, smtp

I have a problem with postfix.
I followed all description from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix.
And it worked perfect except smtp authentication.

I've suffered that mail.log always told "password verification fail" when email sending through my server for a while. Finally I reached that it all happened due to postfix chroot.

My master.cf file is following.

```
 ==========================================================================
 smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
 #smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
 #smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
 #dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
 #tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
 submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
```

When I once made symbol link of /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd at /var/run, it smtp worked well.
but, this /var/run folder is volatile so this symbol link just gone after rebooting.
Moreover, I don't see any this manual symbol link trick in official ubuntu documentation, which I want to avoid.

Any suggestion and advice for me?

Answer (score 1):

creating a permanent mount point using `/etc/fstab` should help.  This method is explained in section `Add binding for saslauthd in Postfix` of https://github.com/webmin/webmin/issues/58

Comment: Hello clement Thanks for your answer. But I still have problem for force to mount directory.  If noaouto mount doesn't mean I can initiate smtp automatically after reboot,  it also means that I can not follow Debian standard guide line.